# Sinatra Streaming and Eventmachine Channels

Tags: ruby, sinatra, eventmachine

With Sinatra Streaming is there a way to specify which connections get sent information. For instance only users on a specific account.

I believe this can be done using Eventmachine Channels but I don't know how. Any advice or even better sample code would be appreciated.

Below is the relevant portion of the code. Right now as you can see it just sends to every open connection.

```
configure do
    set server: 'thin', connections: []
    set :app_file, __FILE__
    set :port, ENV['PORT']
    set :public_folder, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/public'
end

get '/stream', provides: 'text/event-stream' do
    stream :keep_open do |out|
        settings.connections << out
        out.callback { settings.connections.delete(out) }
    end
end

post '/update/contact/:id' do
    @contact = Contact.get(params[:id])
    @contact.update(params[:contact])
    settings.connections.each { |out| out << "data: #{@contact.account_id} Contact #{@contact.id} #{@contact.first_name} #{@contact.last_name}\n\n" }
    204
end
```

Comment: I'm actually struggling with the same thing right now.

Comment: @codefor5 I am facing a similar technical challenge, could you post the solution you used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditions. In your case you could use the authorization example provided in the Sinatra Readme and have two exact same routes with different authorizations. That way if the first condition fails it will check the second route and should then stream. There might be a one route solution but haven't yet experimented with streaming.

Comment: Thanks - I think I understand. Could you clarify by posting my code modified?

Comment: BTY - I am using authorization. There are individual accounts and individual users for those accounts. I want to stream info only between users on the same account.

Comment: I think I gave the wrong answer... Check the Readme under Conditions for just one route if the user is authorized (https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/README.rdoc) That should do. You can set your own conditions based on your auth system.

Comment: I'm not sure I am being clear. Each person logged in has an open connection and it works. How do I send to only that person's connection or a specific group of people's connections instead of everyone with a connection?